# Loop through a Grid to find a specific column (Not in any Grid Events)

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, foreach, ado

I'm in a fix here guys. Working on a Existing Code and need to make changes within the borders.

Need to loop though a (Newly created) Gridview to find a value of a specific Column. And iterating through the rows using an **existing counter(x) and an** **"existing foreach"**.

```
int x = 0;

foreach (KeyValuePair<int, object> kvpValues in tjSelectFields.SectionList)
{
   //This is the Code I've tried out.
   //This is where any new changes are to be added 
     foreach (System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRow row in grdReleaseUserPending.Rows)
     {
        //selectID = grdReleaseUserPending.Rows[x].Cells[1].Text;
          selectID = row.Cells[0].Text;
     }
   //End of New Changes               

    branchID = ((TJSearchRecord)kvpValues.Value).FieldValues["BranchID"];
    acctNbr = ((TJSearchRecord)kvpValues.Value).FieldValues["AcctNbr"];
    txnSeqNbr = ((TJSearchRecord)kvpValues.Value).FieldValues["TxnSeqNbr"];

    txnsList = "'" + selectID + "|" + branchID + "|" + acctNbr + "|" + txnSeqNbr + "'";

    scriptTxnList.Append("oReleaseUserAuthPending.txnsList[" + x + "] = " + txnsList + ";\n");

    x++;                  
 }
```

Basically what I need to do is that I need to use the existing incrementor (x) to increment the Row and get the First Column's data for each row.

Currently the process isn't flowing in the newly created foreach loop

I might have confused you guys a bit with the explanation, if any further info is needed please let me know.

Need help to find out a method to do it.
PFA a screenshot of the grid of reference.

[image: Screenshot of the Grid]

Answer (score 0):

There is no data in that column, only a checkbox. When you bind data to a GridView, all datatypes become a string (or a checkbox when a boolean and autogenerated columns). That is why you should loop the source data and not the GridView contents. A lot of people make this mistake with decimal, currency and dates when trying to get those datatypes back from a cell.Text.

You can however add `DataKeyNames` to the GridView and read those.

```
<asp:GridView ID="grdReleaseUserPending" runat="server" DataKeyNames="selectID">
```

And then read the key in code behind

```
int cnt = 0;
foreach (GridViewRow row in grdReleaseUserPending.Rows)
{
    selectID = Convert.ToInt32(grdReleaseUserPending.DataKeys[cnt].Values[0]);
    cnt++;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response @VDWWD, but the issue still continues. The process still doesn't flow in the foreach loop. :(

Comment: Then there are no rows in `grdReleaseUserPending` or KeyValuePairs in `tjSelectFields`. Set breakpoints and check.

Comment: There are 2 rows in the Grid @VDWWD. (As seen in the Snapshot). And the same is being fetched in the KeyValuePairs...Double checked it

Comment: Are you perhaps trying to loop before `DataBind()` on the GridView is called?